# Use list comprehension to move data from an array to another array using index of a 3rd array

Tags: python

I was am trying to find more efficent and faster way of unpacking a list of objects into its component parts. The approach i have currently working is this:

```
points_fill_v2 = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(points,
                                                            voxel_size=vox)
scrap = points_fill_v2 .get_voxels()
resize3d = np.ones((3, 64, 64, 64))

for idx in range(len(scrap)):
    resize3d[0, scrap[idx].grid_index[0], scrap[idx].grid_index[1], scrap[idx].grid_index[2]] = scrap[idx].color[0]
    resize3d[1, scrap[idx].grid_index[0], scrap[idx].grid_index[1], scrap[idx].grid_index[2]] = scrap[idx].color[1]
    resize3d[2, scrap[idx].grid_index[0], scrap[idx].grid_index[1], scrap[idx].grid_index[2]] = scrap[idx].color[2]
```

`scrap` is a list and looks like this:

```
[Voxel with grid_index: (7, 27, 30), color: (0, 0, 1), Voxel with grid_index: (32, 9, 8), color: (0, 0, 0), ......]
```

It has 2 properties; grid index and color, both are numpy 1,3 arrays.

The above code converts a point cloud into a voxel dataset using open3d (I have to use open3d), and then converts that into a RGB 3d numpy array.

I can split out the main list into 2 other lists (and then arrays) using:

```
grid = [scrap[idx].grid_index for idx in range(len(scrap))]
colour = [scrap[idx].color for idx in range(len(scrap))]
```

How do I transfer the data in colour into `resize_3d` efficiently using the index stored in `grid`?

Comment: Easiest way is to convert scrap into a numpy 2-d array as well and insert it in one go. I am not really sure what the structure is, but if you supply an example of how scrap looks like, I or someone else might be able to help

Comment: scrap looks like this:

[Voxel with grid_index: (7, 27, 30), color: (0, 0, 1),
 Voxel with grid_index: (32, 9, 8), color: (0, 0, 0)......]

It has 2 properties grid index and color both a numpy 1,3 arrays

Comment: Hi, if you have data to add you should edit the question and add it there. also format it using code snippet format

Answer (score 0):

This refactoring should give you a slight speed increase, and makes your code a lot cleaner:

```
from itertools import product
 
points_fill_v2 = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(points, voxel_size=vox)
scrap = points_fill_v2.get_voxels()
resize3d = np.ones((3, 64, 64, 64))

for (idx, scrap_elem), j in product(enumerate(scrap), range(3)):
    resize3d[(j, *scrap_elem.grid_index[:3])] = scrap_elem.color[j]
```

Things I've done here:

- I've used [`enumerate(<sequence>)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) instead of `range(len(<sequence>))`.
- I've used [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to reduce three lines of code into one.
- I've used [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation), combined with [star-unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment), to simplify some of your list-indexing code, which also has the effect of reducing the number of [dot-lookups](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) per iteration.

Comment: Hi Alex,

thanks for the reponse. have a look at http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.html for the documentation on the create from point cloud.

I have had a look at the code and i get:

    resize3d[j, *scrap_elem.grid_index[:2]] = scrap_elem.color[j]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hmm, okay — try replacing that line with two lines. 1st line: `a,b,c = scrap_elem.grid_index[:2]`. 2nd line: `resize3d[j, a, b, c] = scrap_elem.color[j]`. If it works I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the original line is fine as it is if you just add a set of brackets around the expression: `resize3d[(j, *scrap_elem.grid_index[:2])] = scrap_elem.color[j]`

Comment: hi alex,
that works, but i had to make the following changes:

    for (idx, scrap_elem), j in product(enumerate(scrap), range(3)):
        # print(j)
        a, b, c = scrap_elem.grid_index[:3]
        resize3d[j, a, b, c] = scrap_elem.color[j]

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part, apologies. I have edited my answer — hopefully it's correct now.